# What's wrong with this modulo?

Tags: javascript, modulo

[Console modulo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pebGO.png)

When I doing an exercise on Free Code Camp, I find out this error - the result of `96.74%20` was `16.739999999999995`, not `16.74`. What's wrong with it and how can I fix this error?

```js
console.log(96.74%20); // 16.739999999999995
```

Comment: You can use:  `console.log((96.74%20).toFixed(2));`

Comment: This is the effect of floating point rounding error.  Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Any Number object in javascript has a method called "toFixed" that will return the same number rounded to the Nth decimal round: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed . In your case, using .toFixed(2) is just enough. In any case, such an error is related to **floating points rounding errors**, you may check some in google if you're interested to know what it is and why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log((96.74%20).toFixed(2)); // 16.739999999999995
```